# Unable to insert query with special characters in sqllite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have tried to insert rows with special characters in sqllite db. 
The query is as follows:

```
  Insert into table "abc"("id","Name")values ('2','*!@%^#~_(EEEWEEee,><|}{)^$#@?/.')
```

It shows the error as unrecognized token. But in SQL server alone it gets inserted. Please let me know is there any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using SQLite or SQL Server? Your `VALUES` clause ends abruptly in `"` ?

Comment: It looks like your `'` are not set correctly. _VALUES('FirstColumn','2ndColumn','3rdColumn')_

Comment: using sqllite only.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should not contain `table` after `into`

This will work fine (I just tested it on SQLite)

```
 Insert into "abc"("id","Name")values ('2','*!@%^#~_(EEEWEEee,><|}{)^$#@?/.')
```

Results :

```
SELECT * FROM "abc";

id  name
2   *!@%^#~_(EEEWEEee,><|}{)^$#@?/.
```